# Can I call HTTP post on a service in Angular 9 recursively

Tags: typescript

I need to post data (batch) to external api and the batches cannot exceed more than 5 accounts per request. So I have used the code to chunk the array into small chunks like below and then in a loop call the http service  and pass the chunked data.

But the problem is the api in the backend gets executed simultaneously. I am not sure how to wait for the first call in angular and then initiate the next call to the service and so on till I reach the end of the loop.

```
chunk(arr, chunkSize) {
if (chunkSize <= 0) throw "Invalid chunk size";
var R = [];
for (var i=0,len=arr.length; i<len; i+=chunkSize)
  R.push(arr.slice(i,i+chunkSize));
return R;
}



submitReport():void{

//uniquechildids =[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10];
//break into small chunks
const chunkedAccounts = this.chunk(uniquechildids,5);
//output [1,2,3,4,5] [6,7,8,9,10]

let i = 0;
//loop through the chunked array and create params
for(let account of chunkedAccounts ) {
   const rParam = new ReportParamsModel();
   rParam.childIds = account;
   
   //call the backend service that calls the api in C#
   this.reportService.submitReport(rParam).subscribe(result => {
      if(result.statuscode == 200){
      //do some stuff here
      }
      this.loadingMessage = `Submitted batch ${i} of ${chunkedAccounts .length}`;
   },
   error=>{
   console.log(error);
   });
 i++;
}
```

Backend api is hitting simultaneously twice or whatever the chunkedAccount length is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use async/await and wait for each call:

```
chunk(arr, chunkSize) {
  if (chunkSize <= 0) throw "Invalid chunk size";
  const R = [];
  for (let i = 0, len = arr.length; i < len; i += chunkSize)
    R.push(arr.slice(i, i + chunkSize));
  return R;
}

async submitReport(): Promise<void> {

  //uniquechildids =[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10];
  //break into small chunks
  const chunkedAccounts = this.chunk(uniquechildids,5);
  //output [1,2,3,4,5] [6,7,8,9,10]

  let i = 0;
  //loop through the chunked array and create params
  for(let account of chunkedAccounts) {
    const rParam = new ReportParamsModel();
    rParam.childIds = account;
  
    //call the backend service that calls the api in C#
    try {
      const result = await this.reportService.submitReport(rParam).toPromise();
      if(result.statuscode === 200){
        //do some stuff here
      }
      this.loadingMessage = `Submitted batch ${i} of ${chunkedAccounts .length}`;
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
    i++;
  }
}
```

Here is a short example:

```js
async function f(i) {
    console.log('Starting: ' + i);
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        setTimeout(() => {
            console.log('Finished: ' + i);
            if (i > 3) reject('Error: i > 3');
            resolve();
        }, 1000);
    });
}

async function submitReport() {
  const chunkedAccounts = [1, 2, 3, 4]

  for(let account of chunkedAccounts) {
    try {
      await f(account);
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  }
}

submitReport();
```

Comment: thank you, I did try await yet still calls the api endpoint simultaneously.

Comment: @snowflakes74 Are you simultaneously calling `submitReport` multiple times?

Comment: .toPromise() did the trick and it is now working as expected. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

One possibility is to put the server call inside a function and on a successful submit, call the function again to submit the next chunk. Something like this:

```
let accounts = uniquechildids

const work = () => {
    const chunk = accounts.splice(0, 5); // Get first 5 (Modifies the original)

    if(chunk.length === 0) {
        return; // Done
    }

    const rParam = new ReportParamsModel();
    rParam.childIds = chunk;

    this.reportService.submitReport(rParam).subscribe(result => {
        if(result.statuscode == 200){
            work(); // Submit next chunk
        }
        this.loadingMessage = `Submitted batch ${i} of ${accounts.length}`;
    },
    error => {
       console.log(error);
    });
}

work(); // Send the first batch
```

**Edit:** The following should also work and might be better depending on the situation. Calls `work` with all submittable accounts. Sends the first 5 and on a successful callback recursively calls itself with the rest of the accounts.

```
const work = (accounts) => {
    const head = accounts.slice(0, 5);
    const tail = accounts.slice(5);

    if(head.length === 0) {
        return; // Done
    }

    const rParam = new ReportParamsModel();
    rParam.childIds = head;

    this.reportService.submitReport(rParam).subscribe(result => {
        if(result.statuscode == 200){
            work(tail); // Work on others
        }
    },
    error => {
       console.log(error);
    });
}

work(uniquechildids);
```

Comment: A+ for very neat solution.I will try it.

Comment: The issue with the above solution is in my particular scenario , uniquechildids can be any number from < 5 till 250 so accounts.slice(0,5) will fail.

Comment: I noticed I had written down negative slice value for the tail slice. Fixed it. Both `slice(0,5)` and `slice(5)` should work regardless of the length of the array. `slice(0,5)` will return up to 5 first items and `slice(5)` will return everything after the 5th item. If array is less than 5 elements then the tail will just be an empty array.